# Strange artifacts when resize image with php and GD

Tags: php, jpeg, gd, image-resizing

I'am resizing very large jpg images (4164x4724) to 1/8 of their original size using GD library in php and saving them to webp format. Images of clothes contain very detailed structure of the cloth, which results in very strange artifacts in my resized image - see picture below. **How to avoid it?** I have tried some filters like smooth or blur. Problem persists also when saving to JPG format.

PHP Version 7.1.33, GD version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

[example image with desription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VE2l.png)

```
// load image
$localFilename = '../items-22/75/full/210_00_A_xl.jpg';
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($localFilename);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($localFilename);

// resize to 1/8
$newwidth = $width/8;
$newheight = $height/8;
$medium = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresized($medium, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// save image
imagewebp($medium, '../items-22/75/medium/test.webp', 90);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Oh my dear - I should use imagecopyresampled() instead of imagecopyresized(). Problem solved.